# updae table in VUE request api

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm learning about VUE and i have a simple request in an API that gives me infos about prices of the bitcoins. I'd like to update the table every second and i wonder how to do it in the easiest way. Here is my simple code

```
async mounted() {
const res = await fetch(
  "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&parkline=false"
);
const data = await res.json();
this.coins = data;
this.filteredCoins = data;
```

}

I'd like to do this request and update the table in my screen every second pls.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval` and a lambda function to capture the `this` context. In another unmount hook, you might want to clear the interval timer.

```js
async mounted() {
const doFetch = ()=> {
 const res = await fetch(
  "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&parkline=false"
);
 const data = await res.json();
 this.coins = data;
 this.filteredCoins = data;
}
 setInterval(doFetch, 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define an interval to fetch data every second like this:

```js
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      coins: [],
      filteredCoins: []
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    setInterval(this.getData, 1000)
  },

  methods: {
    async getData() {
      const res = await fetch(
        'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&parkline=false'
      );
      const data = await res.json();
      this.coins = data;
      this.filteredCoins = data;
    }
  }
}
```